# Как изменить пакет в android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Добрый день, товарищи разработчики! Сегодня нужно отдавать приложение заказчику, а он сказал, что поменял домен и просит изменить имя пакета в проекте. По этому вопрос такой: как изменить имя главного пакета с ru.rte.ret.app на com.rte.app?

Answer (score 4):

Используйте рефакторинг: правой клавишей мыши по имени пакета -> Refactor -> Rename...

Перед этим нужно ещё убрать галочку “Compact Empty Middle Packages”:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И, если до этого имя пакета выглядело как

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то после этого действия имя вид будет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И после этого уже можно менять каждое из имён по отдельности (менять необходимые имена можно, как и было описано выше, выбрав из контекстного меню Refactor – > Rename... )

Comment: Попробовал, но из всего пакета ru.rte.ret.app изменить могу только последнее app

Comment: @Павел, ответ изменён)

Comment: Да, работает! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Если ты хочешь поправить только пакет, то править его нужно в Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ru.example">
```

Путь до твоих .java файлов это просто путь, который был определен по имени пакета.
В gradle модуля app по имени пакета определен **applicationId "ru.example"**

Можно сделать проще, отрефакторить как указала Ксения.

Comment: Спасибо! Учту в следующих проектах.